# SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA() function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this trouble

```
declare
cursor tab is
    select symbol, SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(geom, 0.1)
    from budynki2
    order by 2 desc;
begin
    for x in tab loop
        dbms_output.put_line(x.symbol || ' ' ||x.geom);
    end loop;
end;
```

Still I get a error that PLS-00302: component 'GEOM' must be declared

I don't know how I can get in to values of second's column in my curosor.

;((

Comment: Why did you write "geom"? What is it? If you copy/pasted it from some example, you should adjust it and use column from your table.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table `budynki2`(do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @Littlefoot `GEOM` should be alias name of the column in Cursor which OP had missed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
declare
cursor tab is
    select symbol, SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(b.geom, 0.1)
    from budynki2 b
    order by 2 desc;
begin
    for x in tab loop
        dbms_output.put_line(x.symbol || ' ' ||x.geom);
    end loop;
end;
```

by aliasing your table `budynki2` as `b`, and prefix your column geom with this alias as `b.geom`. Assuming you have a column named `geom` in your table of type `SDO_GEOMETRY`, you may have another object, in your schema, whose name is `geom`, and that ambigious definition causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Still I get a error that PLS-00302: component 'GEOM' must be declared
> ```

In your cusor there is no column name `GEOM` (column still present in table but cursor not able to identify) and that is what Oracle reporting. You just need to alias your `SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA` as `GEOM` and rest should work.

```
DECLARE
     CURSOR TAB
     IS
          SELECT   SYMBOL,
                   SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA (GEOM, 0.1) AS GEOM
              FROM BUDYNKI2
          ORDER BY 2 DESC;
BEGIN
     FOR X IN TAB
     LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (X.SYMBOL || ' ' || X.GEOM);
     END LOOP;
END;
```

See Demo:

Table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE cola_markets (
  2    mkt_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  3    name VARCHAR2(32),
  4    shape SDO_GEOMETRY);

Table created.

    SQL> INSERT INTO cola_markets VALUES(
      2    1,
      3    'cola_a',
      4    SDO_GEOMETRY(
      5      2003,  
      6      NULL,
      7      NULL,
      8      SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3), 
      9      SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,1, 5,7) 
     10    )
     11  );

    1 row created.

    SQL> INSERT INTO cola_markets VALUES(
      2    2,
      3    'cola_b',
      4    SDO_GEOMETRY(
      5      2003,  
      6      NULL,
      7      NULL,
      8      SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1),
      9      SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(5,1, 8,1, 8,6, 5,7, 5,1)
     10    )
     11  );

    1 row created.

    SQL> INSERT INTO cola_markets VALUES(
      2    3,
      3    'cola_c',
      4    SDO_GEOMETRY(
      5      2003,  
      6      NULL,
      7      NULL,
      8      SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1), 
      9      SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(3,3, 6,3, 6,5, 4,5, 3,3)
     10    )
     11  );

    1 row created.

    SQL> commit;
```

Block:

**Error Simulation:**

You need to note that even though my table has column named `SHAPE`, when i used it in for loop , it produced error. Same as your case.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2       CURSOR TAB
  3       IS
  4            SELECT name, SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(shape, 0.005)
  5      FROM cola_markets 
  6      ORDER BY 2 DESC;
  7  BEGIN
  8       FOR X IN TAB
  9       LOOP
 10            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (X.NAME || ' ' || X.shape);
 11       END LOOP;
 12  END;
 13  /
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (X.NAME || ' ' || X.shape);
                                                   *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 52:
PLS-00302: component 'SHAPE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 10, column 11:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

**Remedy**

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2       CURSOR TAB
  3       IS
  4            SELECT name, 
               SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(shape, 0.005) AS GEOM --<-Alised the column and problem is resolved
  5      FROM cola_markets 
  6      ORDER BY 2 DESC;
  7  BEGIN
  8       FOR X IN TAB
  9       LOOP
 10            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (X.NAME || ' ' || X.GEOM);
 11       END LOOP;
 12  END;
 13  /

cola_a 24
cola_b 16.5
cola_c 5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```